# Reduce discrete linear voltage regulator dropout

Tags: power-supply, power, mosfet

I am investigating the following circuit taken from [here](http://electronicdesign.com/power/efficiently-reduce-high-supply-voltages-accurate-low-voltage) which works fine in simulation. However, while Vout rising linearly with Vin it shows a ~800mV dropout, which I don't quite understand.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYb2L7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What rate are you rising Vin at (mV per second or V per milli second)? What load have you got connected? What is the output when the input is stable 3.8V?

Comment: I currently only investigate the static behaviour that is sweeping Vin. I see stable 3.6V out @ 4.3V input with no load. Of course a load results in further drop-out since the on-resistance of the FET is rather large. But this is not an issue since load will be <1mA anyway.

Comment: That's a 0.7V drop-out. What are you expecting from a source follower regulator?

Comment: I simply would like to know where it comes from. Moreso since this is only a simulation yet.

Comment: As andy says (not in these words) you are chopping off the branch that you are sitting on. R1 provides ON drive to the MOSFET and as Vout approaches Vin your drive approaches 0V. If you want ~=0.000V dropout you must either provide a source of drive from a voltage > Vin or you must use an opposite polarity switch for M1 so it gets drive of ~= Vout - Vgnd = Vout. You will need another active device (or excessive cunning) to invert the drive sense of the TLV431, but this is very low cost and adds a minimal amount of extra components.

Comment: You can't expect the same dropout performance as a commercial LDO with this circuit, OTOH, stability is easier to guarantee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn an N channel MOSFET on you need to have the gate voltage higher than the source voltage by a certain amount. Turn this the other way around; the source has to be lower than the gate by a certain amount for the FET to start conducting.

In your circuit, the gate voltage can be no higher than the drain voltage therefore, the source has to be lower that the drain for the device to start conducting. How much you may ask. It all depends on the FET; some have a gate-source threshold voltage that is several volts. On your device it is between 0.4v and 1.3V - this voltage will cause the device to start conducting a current of 100uA - read the [data sheet](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CD4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.onsemi.com%2Fpub%2FCollateral%2FEN6559-D.PDF&ei=cBhNU_uLLome7Aaeu4DABA&usg=AFQjCNGf09N24yz5urI29D1p1rC8OVJCLQ&bvm=bv.64764171,d.ZGU) page 2. If your FET model has the parameter \$V_{GS(THRESHOLD)}\$ then try altering that to see what effect it makes.

Comment: how is this circuit achieving regulation, is it actually oscillating like with a PWM control scheme? so the gate voltage goes up and down turning it on and off? if so, is that actually a linear regulator?

Comment: @IonTodirel I was answering a question about drop-out voltage and not fully explaining how the circuit operates. If you want to know how it works use a sim tool like LTSpice.