# Trying to do a circuit to variate voltage from GND to VCC using MOSFET and transistor

Tags: circuit-analysis

The circuit I am doing is this one in the post, but it only variates the voltage just like a key it goes direct from 0 to 12V. What I want is that it variates the voltage from 0 to VCC in little intervals, just like a dimmer.

[image: Circuit with mosfet N and transistor, activated by a nodemcu pwm]

Comment: Try using a 1 kohm emitter resistor and see the improvement. However, it still won't be perfect because you need an op-amp to control things properly AND a slightly larger supply voltage like 15 volts.

Comment: *just like a key* Perhaps you mean "a switch" instead of "a key". The abrupt relation you see is **expected behavior** of a circuit like this. You're controlling the \$V_{BE}\$ of Q2 which means the current through Q2 (and R7) changes **exponentially** depending on V1. That means a **small change** of V1 can cause a **large change** in the current and voltage across R7. MOSFET U3 simply copies that voltage across R8 since U3 is configured as a **source follower**. Maybe you should study **voltage regulator** circuits to find a circuit that does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically trying to build a linear regulator. Your circuit has a poor voltage control because the control sensitivity is strictly determined by turning-on point of the bipolar transistor. Once the supply voltage is high enough to turn Q2 on (Max ~ 1.2V), current will start to flow through it and the gate of the MOSFET U3 will be pulled low, thus shutting the MOSFET down.

There are already many cheap off-the-shelf Linear Regulators you can use, however, if you really want to build one from scratch and with discrete components, you could use a circuit similar to the following:

[image: Circuit]

Source: [Link to Circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106627/reduce-discrete-linear-voltage-regulator-dropout)

Essentially you would connect a pot in series with R3 (in order to keep a minimum resistance) and regulate the feedback through it.

The way the circuit works is as follows. At startup the MOSFET is connected in a diode configuration and its gate-source voltage is higher than its gate threshold voltage, thus it is on. As the output voltage increases, so does the feedback voltage formed by R2 and R3. Once the Feedback voltage reaches 2.5V, the shunt-regulator TL431 is turned on and begins to sink current through its cathode, therefore pulling down the gate of the MOSFET, which in turn shuts it down. This negative feedback leads to a controlled output voltage given by:

$$V_{out} \approx 2.5V \cdot \frac{R_2 + R_3}{R_3} $$